# psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, airflow

An airflow instance loaded with few dags. Airflow instance is using LocalExecutor with PostgresSQL as metastore. It crashes suddenly with error below. Issue is not so frequent. What mistake am i doing ?

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: The error message `Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?` is good place to start. Is the Postgres server running and is it listening on `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Looks like something is killing the postgressql  process. but why it killing it thats reason i am looking for.

Comment: Then you will need to look at the system logs.